# spring boot use file path both in eclipse and after build

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, gradle, buildpath

I'm developing spring boot program using json input.
when I build spring boot from build.gradle file, I copy resources from src/main/resources to deploy/config.

Now, I want to use my json file in Eclipse and after build, but file path is different.
In eclipse, file path is src/main/resources/input/a.json and After build, file path is deploy/config/input/a.json

this is my build.gradle

```
task deploy() {
    doLast{      
        delete ('deploy')
        copy {
            from "src/main/resources"
            into "deploy/config"
            include "*/"
        }
        copy {
            from "build/libs/${rootProject.name}-${version}.jar"
            into "deploy/"
        }
    }
}
```

And my java source code is like this.

```
String path1="config/input/"+fileName;
String path2="src/main/resources/input"+fileName;
```

How can I write file path just one way? I can't modify all the time when I build.

Thank you! :D

Comment: Do you really need to move it to `deploy/config`? This surely makes your life harder :)

Comment: What is the purpose of copying resources to `deploy/config` folder?

Comment: I don't care whereever file is, I just thought the only way to use file after buiild is put files in somewhere. and there was deploy/config. Do I have another choice?

Comment: resources can simply be packaged in the jar and used with a simple `getResourceAsStream`

Comment: sorry I've tried, but It doesn't work because I just have to get path. I don't have to get resources.